# Как запретить авторизованному пользователю сохранять заметки от чужого имени?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, mvc, url

Пишу приложение под ASP .NET Core, смысл которого в следующем:

Есть пользователь, при авторизации он может оставлять тайные (типо никто не видит) заметки (для себя).

Вопрос: что мне нужно использовать, чтобы не дать отправить секретную заметку **от имени другого пользователя**?

Моя идея состоит в следующем:

При авторизации создаем экземпляр класса User, который подтягивает данные (id, email, password) из БД (PostgreSQL) и за счёт передачи по страницам (представлениям / views) одного и того же экземпляра, данные, которые он изменил в самой ссылке -> никак ему не помогут.

Comment: ничего не понял в последних абзацах, но, чтобы сделать то что вы хотите, совершенно достаточно сохранять в БД код пользователя для заметки при её создании и читать заметки только по коду пользователя, который нужно получить из Claim-ов аутентифицированного пользователя.

Comment: Под кодом пользователя имеется ввиду id?
У меня две таблицы в БД: User и Note.
User имеет: id, email, password.
Note имеет: id, author_id, text, date_time (PostgreSQL выдаёт ошибки из-за заглавных букв).
Получается, что имеющееся поле author_id в БД у Note - это и есть защита?

Answer (score 0):

Создайте таблицу в БД note, где будут следующие столбцы:

- UserID - guid пользователя, который оставил заметку
- Message - string текст заметки
- Date - datetime время создания

В C# при добавлении в Бд строки используйте Guid авторизованного пользователя. Чтоб вытащить из бд - "Select * note Where UserID - '{id}'"